# Passing variable to queryset in Form class

Tags: python, django

I use django-mptt-autocomplete, for tree-view my hierarhy in template.

```
fosmotr_techobject = TechObject.objects.order_by('tree_id', 'lft')
    class lookupForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Osmotr
            fields = ('Osmotr_ostanovka', 'Osmotr_techobject', )        
            exclude = ('Osmotr_ostanovka', )
            widgets = {
                'Osmotr_techobject': FancyTreeWidget(queryset=fosmotr_techobject,model=Osmotr),
                'Osmotr_ostanovka': forms.HiddenInput()     
            }
```

But I need to filter queryset in widgets, and this is problem.

If I try set queryset inside Form class - it don`t work

```
NameError: name 'fosmotr_techobject' is not defined
```

When I try get queryset from function - it don`t work too

```
def get_zavod(route_id):
    zzavod = Marshrut.objects.filter(id=route_id).values_list('marshrut_Zavod', flat=True)
    fosmotr_techobject = TechObject.objects.filter(TechObject_zavod__in = zzavod).order_by('tree_id', 'lft')
    return fosmotr_techobject       

class lookupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Osmotr
        fields = ('Osmotr_ostanovka', 'Osmotr_techobject', )        
        exclude = ('Osmotr_ostanovka', )
        widgets = {
            'Osmotr_techobject': FancyTreeWidget(queryset=get_zavod(route),model=Osmotr),
            'Osmotr_ostanovka': forms.HiddenInput()     }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        route = kwargs.pop('route', None)
```

I pass route to **init** from views

```
def lookup_add(request, route_id, stop_id):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/routes/login/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = lookupForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                lookup = form.save(commit=False)
                lookup.Osmotr_ostanovka_id = stop_id
                lookup.save()           
                return redirect('/routes/stops/get/' + stop_id + '/') 
        else:
            form = lookupForm(route = route_id)
        return render(request, 'lookup_add.html', {'form': form, 'username': auth.get_user(request)})
```

same error

```
  NameError: name 'route' is not defined
```

My models:

```
class Zavod(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "zavod"
    zavod_kod = models.CharField(max_length = 4, primary_key=True)
    zavod_text = models.CharField(max_length = 59)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.zavod_text

class Marshrut(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "marshrut"
    marshrut_text = models.CharField(max_length = 59)
    marshrut_Zavod = models.ForeignKey(Zavod, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.marshrut_text

class TechObject(MPTTModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "techObject"
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['TechObject_text']    
    TechObject_SAPid = models.CharField(max_length = 59, primary_key=True)
    TechObject_zavod = models.ForeignKey(Zavod, null=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.TechObject_text

 class Osmotr(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "osmotr"
    Osmotr_ostanovka = models.ForeignKey(Ostanovka, null=True)
    Osmotr_techobject = models.ForeignKey(TechObject, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I also tried bad way with global var, but without result.

Comment: All your errors are so obvious, you were using variables that are either not defined, or you thought you defined them but the variable is actually not in the scope. You can read up http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html about python scope. That might help you.